# Upgrade SSL/TLS/Openssl?

Tags: linux, web-server, rhel6, vulnerabilities, vulnerability

I have a requirement to upgrade SSL/TLS/OpenSSL. The server is RHEL 6 Enterprise.

In that server I am going to remove apache, which has not been not in use for a  long time. After uninstalling apache , is it stil necessary to upgrade ssl/tls/openssl?

Or even broader, since neither a web server nor a webbrowser will be installed is there any need for OpenSSL at all?

Comment: Is there a particular vulnerability you're worried about? Or are you just looking to reduce the number of packages to reduce your attack surface?

Comment: Hi everybody..sorry, One correction..I want to use web browser. After uninstallation of web server, is there any need for ssl/tls/openssl at all?

Comment: Yes. Because of vulnerability reason I have got this requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing unneeded software is typically a good idea.

The openssl package is actually needed for a lot of required core functionality in a RHEL system.

```
 sudo yum remove openssl
```

will fail but also show what also would have to be removed since it depends on openssl.

So do the right thing and upgrade the openssl package to the current patch level.

Comment: Dear Lain and HBruijn...whatabout SSL and TLS ??

Comment: openssl is the most commonly used shared software library to provide SSL/TLS functionality and features to other software.

Comment: @Ratheesh We'll leave that as a learning exercise for you.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the output of

```
yum remove openssl
```

It will list all of the packages that will also be removed because they depend upon the openssl package. Eventually it will quit with the error message

> Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected

Removing openssl from your system is not practical or desirable.

Keeping it up-to-date with that provided by your distro is though desireable and practical.